# iOS change view from scrollview to tableview

Tags: uitableview, uiscrollview

i created this view with the help of scrollview but i need to create this view with tableview, what is a best way to do this. should i break views in sections, or is there any other way around?

image  of the view is attached.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the `Title1` and `Title2` are selectable and part of the `UIScrollView`, as for the rest Heading as sections and the content as `UITableViewCells`.

Comment: i want everything in tableview, so if user scrolls then all of the thing scrolls

Comment: What should be "tapable"?

Comment: everything is displayable only, nothing is clickable and data is coming from previous view controller, in the end there will be a share button which will share it as pdf.

Comment: Ok then I would go with Title1, Title2 and Heading as sections and the interior of the heading as cells.

Comment: so i need to create one view for the header which contain label + price (depending on condition)and body part as a prototype cell containing data.

Comment: Could be yes. I would recommend use reusable sections and cells.

Comment: can you please provide me snippets for that ?